# javascript issue - firefox

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi all Why this piece of javascript code doesn't work on firefox

```
var nfiles = 1;
function Expand(){
nfiles++
var adh = '<input type="file" name="File '+nfiles+'">';
files.insertAdjacentHTML('BeforeEnd',adh);
return false;
};
```

Comment: Try to analyze the problem using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have no semi-colon after your variable.

Shown below is a working `Expand function` for all browsers including Firefox.

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCve8/).

```
function Expand() {
    nfiles++;
    var files = document.getElementById('test');
    var adh = '<input type="file" name="File ' + nfiles + '">';
    files.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', adh);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment about the alternative use of quotes. Cheers!

Comment: Your welcome. Side Note: I looked at your open questions to see how I can help. You should hopefully have more attention to one of your questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where this function comes from, so I can't say anything about that:

```
files.insertAdjacentHTML('BeforeEnd',adh);
```

This is an alternative way of writing the following line; it feels cleare to me, but I must admit it's personal taste:

```
var adh = "<input type=\"file\" name=\"File " + nfiles + "\">";
```

and put a ; after the following line:

```
nfiles++
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the BeforeEnd should be something like this

```
beforeend
```

See here
[insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML)